# Linq running total 1st value added to itself

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below which calculates the running total for a customer account status, however he first value is always added to itself and I'm not sure why - though I suspect I've missed something obvious:

```
    decimal? runningTotal = 0;
    IEnumerable<StatementModel> statement = sage.Repository<FDSSLTransactionHistory>()
        .Queryable()
        .Where(x => x.CustomerAccountNumber == sageAccount)
        .OrderBy(x=>x.UniqueReferenceNumber)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => new StatementModel()
        {
            SLAccountId = x.CustomerAccountNumber,
            TransactionReference = x.TransactionReference,
            SecondReference = x.SecondReference,
            Currency = x.CurrencyCode,
            Value = x.GoodsValueInAccountCurrency,
            TransactionDate = x.TransactionDate,
            TransactionType = x.TransactionType,
            TransactionDescription = x.TransactionTypeName,
            Status = x.Status,
            RunningTotal = (runningTotal += x.GoodsValueInAccountCurrency)
        });
```

Which outputs:

```
29/02/2012 00:00:00 154.80  309.60  
30/04/2012 00:00:00 242.40  552.00  
30/04/2012 00:00:00 242.40  794.40  
30/04/2012 00:00:00 117.60  912.00
```

Where the `309.60` of the first row should be simply `154.80`

What have I done wrong?

**EDIT:**
As per ahruss's comment below, I was calling `Any()` on the result in my View, causing the first to be evaluated twice - to resolve I appended `ToList()` to my query.

Thanks all for your suggestions

Comment: Good question. +1. I can't see why this could be happening. Is there anything we're missing here? How are you outputting it? If I were you I'd start by breaking down the query for debugging purposes. Bring the `Select` onto a new line, check what the `Where` is bringing back first.

Comment: Can you give some example data for what you run your LINQ against?

Comment: Can you post a code(complete program) which reproduces the issue?

Comment: Will do, bear with me - didn't quite expect this response :D

Comment: Is this the only place you modify `runningTotal`? I guess no. I tried something similar which works perfectly. Your question is answerable only if you provide a repro..

Comment: I tried a sample (without your Repository obviously), and was not able to reproduce it. Try incrementing runningTotal in a function `runningTotal += Increment(x)` that just returns GoodsValueInAccountCurrency. Using a breakpoint you can see if the first value indeed gets called twice. It does not seem to be the case.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it either

Comment: You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386184/c-sharp-paradigms-side-effects-on-lists). LINQ with side effects is usually a bad idea. I would do the projection without the running total and then afterwards go back through in a foreach and update the records.

Comment: My guess would be somewhere you are calling `Any()` or `First()`, or something like that before you actually consume the list. That could make the first one be evaluated twice. You *could* fix that, if it is the problem, by adding a `.ToList()` to the end. The better solution is really just to avoid the abuse of LINQ, though. You get no guarantees about what order things will be called when you use LINQ, or how many times. It should be stateless.

Comment: @ahruss that got it! I'm calling `Any()` in my View. Your suggestion resolves it. Could you please post as an answer?

Comment: Simple error. Solution has nothing to do with the code in the question. But it got solved :-D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a `ToList()` to the end of the call to avoid duplicate invocations of the selector.

This is a stateful LINQ query with side-effects, which is by nature unpredictable. Somewhere else in the code, you called something that caused the first element to be evaluated, like `First()` or `Any()`. In general, it is dangerous to have side-effects in LINQ queries, and when you find yourself needing them, it's time to think about whether or not it should just be a `foreach` instead.

## Edit, or Why is this happening?

This is a result of how LINQ queries are evaluated: until you actually *use* the results of a query, nothing really happens to the collection. It doesn't evaluate any of the elements. Instead, it stores [Abstract Expression Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623413/expression-trees-for-dummies) or just the delegates it needs to evaluate the query. Then, it evaluates those only when the results are needed, and unless you explicitly store the results, they're thrown away afterwards, and re-evaluated the next time.

So this makes the question why does it have different results each time? The answer is that `runningTotal` is only initialized the first time around. After that, its value is whatever it was after the last execution of the query, which can lead to strange results.

This means the question could just have easily have been "Why is the total always twice what it should be?" if the asker were doing something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(statement.Count()); // this enumerates all the elements!
foreach (var item in statement) { Console.WriteLine(item.Total); }
```

Because the only way to get the number of elements in the sequence is to actually evaluate all of them.

Similarly, what actually happened in this question was that somewhere there was code like this:

```
if (statement.Any()) // this actually involves getting the first result
{ 
    // do something with the statement
}
// ...
foreach (var item in statement) { Console.WriteLine(item.Total); }
```

It seems innocuous, but if you know how LINQ and IEnumerable work, you know that `.Any()` is basically the same as `.GetEnumerator().MoveNext()`, which makes it more obvious that it requires getting the first element.

It all boils down to the fact that LINQ is based on deferred execution, which is why the solution is to use `ToList`, which circumvents that and forces immediate execution.

Comment: Brilliant question and brilliant answer (+1), but (for my sake) could you explain how evaluating the first element would cause the `Select` to fire (including the increment of `runningTotal`) if `Any()` was called independently? Struggling to understand this one, and I'd like to avoid it in the future.

Comment: Deferred execution is the root cause then? Perhaps that should be part of the answer?

Comment: @DeeMac If by "independently" you mean as a separate query of the same source (`sage.Repository`), then it won't fire. But `statement.Any()` would not be independent because `statement` is the select query itself -- any request to enumerate it will be fulfilled by executing the selector.

Comment: Ohhh I see. I didn't realise Linq worked in this way. I didn't realise that to define a `Select` meant this new 'definition' would be used elsewhere.

Comment: @DeeMac I expanded my answer to explain some more.

Comment: @ahruss Your answer is now way better! Think this is valuable to many people! But the "solution" with `ToList` is somewhat tongue-in-cheek

Comment: @MareInfinitus `ToList` is probably the practical solution for the OP's situation, but you're right that there is a disadvantage in losing the possibility of deferred execution. I added an answer showing the alternative.

Comment: @ahruss foreach over a LINQ expression has some very nice effects due to deferred execution. One should be careful with this. (sorry, can't find an example quick enough now where a foreach prints all identical values for the items)

Comment: @ahruss Here we go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907987/access-to-foreach-variable-in-closure Think this is exactly what your code does, see second example in the accepted answer with 5, 5, 5, 5, 5

Comment: @MareInfinitus That doesn't apply here... There is no closure in a foreach

Comment: @MareInfinitus `foreach` over a query is no problem; the opposite is the problem: a query that refers to a `foreach` variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to freeze the results with `ToList`, a solution to the outer scope variable problem is using an [iterator function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx), like this:

```
IEnumerable<StatementModel> GetStatement(IEnumerable<DataObject> source) {
    decimal runningTotal = 0;
    foreach (var x in source) {
        yield return new StatementModel() {
            ...
            RunningTotal = (runningTotal += x.GoodsValueInAccountCurrency)
        };
    }
}
```

Then pass to this function the source query (not including the `Select`):

```
var statement = GetStatement(sage.Repository...AsEnumerable());
```

Now it is safe to enumerate `statement` multiple times. Basically, this creates an enumerable that re-executes this entire block on each enumeration, as opposed to executing a selector (which equates to only the `foreach` part) -- so `runningTotal` will be reset.